# Excel replace underscore with next character in uppercase and remove underscore

Tags: excel-formula, str-replace

I have some strings like `avg_face_count` and I need to convert them in `avgFaceCount` in Excel
Basically I need to find every underscore in the string, remove it and replace the next underscore character in uppercase
I tried https://superuser.com/questions/996712/excel-findreplace-lowercase-after-a-certain-character
but it only work for one underscore

thanks

Comment: You could try substitute()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SUBSTITUTE(PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(A20,"_"," "))," ","")`

It first replaces `_` for a space character. Then creates Caps for the first character after the space and finally removes the spaces.

If you truly only need the character after `_` to be in caps, then use this Office 365 solution:

```
=LET(cell, A2,
     a,    SEQUENCE(LEN(cell)),
SUBSTITUTE(
           REDUCE( A20, a,
           LAMBDA( b,   c,
IF(MID(b,c,1)="_",
   LEFT(b,c-1)&UPPER(MID(b,c,2))&RIGHT(b,MAX(a)-c-1),
   b))),"_",""))
```

Comment: Awesome I just found this solution too, but thanks

Comment: I updated it with a solution that actually checks for `_` so in case of your example or if the string would contain spaces it would only change the character after a `_`.